# stop scene animation from code python after animation is complete

Tags: python, scripting

I am trying to create a data driven animation face animation using a socket and Modal operator. In each loop of the Modal operator I receive data from a socket , use the data to create the keyframes of the animation and then play the animation. But i am unable to figure out how to stop the animation when the animation has reached the end keyframe.

Here is my code

SocketModalOperator.py

```
            import bpy
            import socket
            import os
            import sys

            absolutePath = "/Users/pulkitjuneja/Documents/projects/EVA/scripts"
            sys.path.append(absolutePath)

            from animationController import main


            class socketModal(bpy.types.Operator):
                bl_idname = "object.modal_operator"
                bl_label = "Lip synch Operator"
                _timer = None

                def __init__(self):
                    print("Listen Start")
                    os.chdir(absolutePath)
                    self.port = 1301

                def __del__(self):
                    print("Listen End")

                def execute(self, context):
                    print ("execute")
                    self.socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
                    self.socket.setblocking(0)
                    self.socket.bind(("127.0.0.1", self.port))
                    print('socket listening on port', self.port)
                    self._timer = context.window_manager.event_timer_add(1.0, context.window)
                    context.window_manager.modal_handler_add(self)
                    return {'RUNNING_MODAL'}

                def modal(self, context, event):
                    print ("modal")
                    if event.type == "TIMER":
                        data = None
                        try:
                            data = self.socket.recv(1024 * 1024)
                        except socket.error:
                            print ("no data") 
                    main(context, data) # call to animation controller
                    if event.type == 'BACK_SLASH':
                        self.socket.close()
                        return {'FINISHED'}
                    return {'PASS_THROUGH'}


            bpy.utils.register_class(socketModal)
```

AnimationController.py

```
            import bpy
            import json

            shapeKeyNames = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'X']
            dataPathPrefix = "key_blocks[\""
            dataPathSuffix = "\"].value"


            def getShapeKeyAnimationInfo(mouthCue, fps):
                frames = (float(mouthCue['end']) - float(mouthCue['start'])) * fps
                frames = round(frames)
                # print(frames)
                phoneme = mouthCue['value']
                for name in shapeKeyNames:
                    if phoneme in name:
                        return (frames, name)


            def addFaceShapeKeyFrame(shapeKeyName, previousKeyName, startFrame, frameCount):
                faceShapeKeyParent = bpy.data.meshes['face'].shape_keys
                dataPath = dataPathPrefix + shapeKeyName + dataPathSuffix
                faceShapeKeyParent.key_blocks[shapeKeyName].value = 0.0
                faceShapeKeyParent.keyframe_insert(dataPath, frame=startFrame)
                faceShapeKeyParent.key_blocks[shapeKeyName].value = 1.0
                finalFrame = startFrame + frameCount
                if previousKeyName != None and previousKeyName != shapeKeyName:
                    dataPathPrevious = dataPathPrefix + previousKeyName + dataPathSuffix
                    faceShapeKeyParent.key_blocks[previousKeyName].value = 0.0
                    faceShapeKeyParent.keyframe_insert(dataPathPrevious, frame=finalFrame)
                faceShapeKeyParent.keyframe_insert(dataPath, frame=finalFrame)


            def addJawShapeKeyFrame(shapeKeyName, previousKeyName, startFrame, frameCount):
                jawShapeKeyParent = bpy.data.meshes['jaw'].shape_keys
                jawKeyName = getJawKeyName(shapeKeyName)
                dataPath = dataPathPrefix + jawKeyName + dataPathSuffix
                previousJawKeyName = None
                if previousKeyName:
                    previousJawKeyName = getJawKeyName(previousKeyName)
                    dataPathPrev = dataPathPrefix + previousJawKeyName + dataPathSuffix
                finalFrame = startFrame + frameCount
                print (jawKeyName , previousJawKeyName)
                if previousJawKeyName != None and previousJawKeyName != jawKeyName:
                    jawShapeKeyParent.key_blocks[jawKeyName].value = 0.0
                    jawShapeKeyParent.keyframe_insert(dataPath, frame=startFrame)
                    jawShapeKeyParent.key_blocks[previousJawKeyName].value = 0.0
                    jawShapeKeyParent.keyframe_insert(dataPathPrev, frame=finalFrame)
                jawShapeKeyParent.key_blocks[jawKeyName].value = 1.0
                jawShapeKeyParent.keyframe_insert(dataPath, frame=finalFrame)


            def getJawKeyName(shapeKeyName):
                if shapeKeyName in ['D', 'H']:
                    return 'W'
                if shapeKeyName in ['C', 'E', 'F', 'G']:
                    return 'M'
                if shapeKeyName in ['X', 'A', 'B']:
                    return 'C'


            def main(context, data):
                scene = context.scene
                scene.render.fps = 60
                fps = scene.render.fps
                clearAllAnimation()
                phonemes = json.loads(data)
                mouthCues = phonemes['mouthCues']
                previousKey = None
                framecounter = 1
                for x in mouthCues:
                    animationData = getShapeKeyAnimationInfo(x, fps)
                    addFaceShapeKeyFrame(animationData[1], previousKey, framecounter, animationData[0])
                    addJawShapeKeyFrame(animationData[1], previousKey, framecounter, animationData[0])
                    previousKey = animationData[1]
                    framecounter += animationData[0]
                scene.frame_set(1)
                scene.frame_end = framecounter + 1
                bpy.ops.screen.animation_play() # Here is where the animation starts playing 


            def clearAllAnimation():
                faceShapeKeyParent = bpy.data.meshes['face'].shape_keys
                faceShapeKeyParent.animation_data_clear()


            if (__name__ == "__main__"):
                main()
```

I can calculate the time required for the animation by multiplying the FPS with the total number of frames added but how do i stop the animation after that time without blocking blender UI

Comment: You can check `context.scene.frame_current`. Have you tried `bpy.ops.screen.animation_cancel()`?

Comment: yea , but how do i call this after the animation has reached a particular frame ?. or after a particular time

Comment: You prob. have this working now.  I'd suggest not using animation play / cancel at all, rather use `scene.frame_set(frame)` where you calculate time, and convert to frame in the operator.  `event_timer_add(1.0,...)` makes the timer click, i.e. send a timer event,  every 1.0 seconds.

Answer (score 1):

Calling some operators from within an operator can [have problems](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/49410/935), but in your case there is nothing special needed. You can simply call the operator as if it was a normal python function.

```
def execute(self, context):
    print ("execute")
    self._timer = context.window_manager.event_timer_add(1.0, context.window)
    context.window_manager.modal_handler_add(self)
    bpy.ops.screen.animation_play()
    return {'RUNNING_MODAL'}

def modal(self, context, event):
    print ("modal")
    if event.type == "TIMER":
        print ("no data, just testing")
    if context.scene.frame_current > 100:
        bpy.ops.screen.animation_cancel()
        return {'FINISHED'}
    return {'PASS_THROUGH'}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [handlers](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.app.handlers.html) to respond to events, you don't even need a modal operator for this.

```
import bpy

def stop_at_last_frame(scene):
    if scene.frame_current == scene.frame_end:
        bpy.ops.screen.animation_cancel()

bpy.app.handlers.frame_change_pre.append(stop_at_last_frame)
print('Registered handler')
```